# how to use output inserted.* into table variable while doing Update

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-update, insert-into

I am trying the Output inserted for the first time and not able to understand the Error Message :

> Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Goal: I have a huge claim table with many accounts. I want to update a value to 1 in a few accounts and be able to display the updates.

SO, I create a @TEMP_tbl  with the accounts that I want to update
*/

```
DECLARE  @TEMP_tbl TABLE(
SORIGCREDITORREFNO VARCHAR(30),
BCLAIMONHOLD INT)

INSERT INTO @TEMP_tbl (SORIGCREDITORREFNO,BCLAIMONHOLD)
VALUES ('1234',0)

-- writing my update statement

DECLARE @MYVAR TABLE ( SORIGCREDITORREFNO VARCHAR(30),BCLAIMONHOLD INT)

UPDATE CLAIM 
SET BCLAIMONHOLD = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @MYVAR
WHERE SORIGCREDITORREFNO IN (SELECT SORIGCREDITORREFNO FROM @TEMP_tbl) 

SELECT * FROM  @MYVAR  
-- want to look at my updates
```

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 Insert Error: Column name or
>   number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace * with field names

```
UPDATE CLAIM 
SET BCLAIMONHOLD = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.SORIGCREDITORREFNO , INSERTED.BCLAIMONHOLD INTO @MYVAR
WHERE SORIGCREDITORREFNO IN (SELECT SORIGCREDITORREFNO FROM @TEMP_tbl)
```

When you specify *, it means all fields from CLAIM table, which is not matched with fields in @MYVAR variable